# How to update a sharepoint 2010 workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a complex workflow, written in VS2010 (not sharepoint designer) for Sharepoint 2010.

Is there a document somewhere (MS?), with the recommended steps, to deploy an updated workflow, without cancelling the existing running instances of the workflow?

I can easily deploy the new workflow, however, the problem is that, I do not want to kill the existing instances of the running workflow (which is what happens by default when you deploy the workflow).

Through trial and error, I have a long list of what I think I need to do, but I really would like some confirmation.

I also need to use the new Package capability to deploy the workflow, since VS.NET will NOT be installed upon the sharepoint production server.

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had struggled myself with this in the past (2007 times) but couldn't find an elegant way out except completing the workflows.

Could this give you pointers - [SharePoint Workflow Versioning with VS 2010](http://philwicklund.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=145)

Comment: Just saw your reply. Thanks a bunch! Looks like most of those steps are the ones I take.